# Is it appropriate or polite to say 'I am here to educate you'?

Tags: meaning, politeness, register

When doing a presentation, is the following introduction

> I am here to educate you
>   (or)
>   Let me educate you

considered polite to say to an audience?

Comment: Edify would sound even better

Comment: Have you looked up *educate* in the dictionary and checked some usage examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess not. If you want to *educate* a person, the implication is that they are *uneducated*. Which may not be a nice thing to say. I'd start with something along the lines of:

***I'm here to talk about // I'd like to present // The thing that I want to focus on is***

If you do feel what you have to say is extremely important and valuable, try:

***This is a unique opportunity for us to***

Of course, the context is everything. If you've established a half-buddy half-boss kind of rapport with the audience, you may say:

***You know nothing and you're dumb - but rich enough to pay my fee and learn what life is about. So STFU and listen.***

And they may applaud it. Who knows?

Answer (score 1):

you can write, **"Let me enlighten you"**

Comment: This sounds like an extremely pompous and sarcastic thing to say.

Answer (score 1):

### Depends on context

In a self-deprecatory or joking manner, it's generally acceptable to western audiences. *Well, I guess i'm supposed to be here to educate you fine folks..*

As a statement of purpose from a position of authority (lecturer or expert), preceding a statement of action it is also generally acceptable.  *I am here to educate you on the interactions of black holes with regular matter today, so I have set up this experiment to show you the blah of blah*..

In any other usage, it can be seen as pompous, implying the audience is uneducated or ignorant, or indicating that the user considers educating the audience to be beneath him or a waste of his time.

Comment: I'm here to educate you ignorant savages, so listen up people!

Answer (score 0):

You can mean that **"I am here to/Let me explain you"**

Answer (score -1):

You can say "I am here to supply what I deem to be missing information about XY". By throwing in "deem" I am making the sentence a bit modest.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Hows my answer now ?

Comment: The OP asks whether "Let me/I am here to educate you" is considered polite. First, I would answer that part and then offer an alternative solution if you agree that the former is inappropriate.